# extract string from string with unknown length

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var largePictureURL = response.d[i];
//for this example see largePictureURL
largePictureURL = "../uploads/191mapTool_thumb.png_tempLargeFileName=mapTool.png"
```

largePictureURL will always contain `_tempLargeFileName` + actual file name. Without knowing the actual file name how I can extract `_tempLargeFileName` + actual file name from `largePictureURL`?

I know how to do it with indexes but as I said I will be unsure of the name of the file. One thing for sure though I want to extract the remaining part of the string.  Please advise

**UPDATE @gurvinder372**

```
//thumbNailUrlANDlargeImageUrl = "../uploads/191mapTool_thumb.png_tempLargeFileName=mapTool.png"

var largePictureURL = thumbNailUrlANDlargeImageUrl.split("_tempLargeFileName=")[1];
//largePictureURL = "mapTool.png"

var thumbnailURL = thumbNailUrlANDlargeImageUrl.split("_thumb." + "png")[0];
//thumbnailURL = "../uploads/191mapTool_thumb.png_tempLargeFileName=mapTool.png"
```

Comment: A bit brittle, but this should work given your example: `var filename = laregPictureURL.split('=')[1];`

Comment: And pray for the filename not contains a "=" ^^

Comment: @SteevePitis exactly :)

Answer (score 4):

> largePictureURL will always contain '_tempLargeFileName' + actual file
>   name.

This is a good enough hint to try this

```
var fileName = largePictureURL.split( "_tempLargeFileName" )[1]
```

and if `=` is also appended after `"_tempLargeFileName"` then modify the same to

```
var fileName = largePictureURL.split( "_tempLargeFileName=" )[1]
```

For getting everything before use the 0th index

```
var before = largePictureURL.split( "_tempLargeFileName=" )[0]
```

Comment: yeah great thanks that worked...what about if I want everything before "_tempLargeFileName=" ...iv tried "_tempLargeFileName=" )[-1] but this didnt work

Comment: @John that is because you are doing split on file extension name, did you tried the example I have shared?

Comment: got it. had an extra . in ..png thanks for the help G

Answer (score 3):

You could use substring of the index like this:

```
var fileName = largePictureURL.substring(largePictureURL.indexOf("_tempLargeFileName"));
```

That will get you everything to the end of the string, starting with "_tempLargeFileName"